The character models have no eyeballs after exporting to FBX
I am a Noob on using Blender.
I want to export some Blender Goo character models to FBX files and use them on Unity.
However, the character models lack eyeballs just like the image below:

But the original .blend files have eyeballs:

What should I do to make the eyeballs display correctly in FBX format?
The steps that I have done to put the models into Unity:

open the .blend file

Unpack the texture files to the folder



File -> External Data -> Uncheck "Auto Pack Resources"


File -> External Data -> Unpack Resources


Export the file to FBX (Path Mode: Copy, Embed Textures)

Copy the texture files and the FBX model to a Unity project

Assign the Textures to the corresponding materials in Unity


After that, every texture maps correctly except the eyeballs.
I tried to find the material that controls the eyeball texture in Blender Goo and you can see it in the image below.  This material shares the texture parts of the face and eyes. I actually see this material in unity. However, after I assigned the Texture to this material. Only the face part displays correctly but no eyeballs in Unity. Then, what should I do to make the eyes also display correctly in FBX format?

These are the models that I want to convert:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11LGnszUR4KKrt17IXqPd4ts0ImPrp-DA

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures
